# Css rotate element 360 back and forth

Tags: html, css, rotation, css-animations

As the question says I'd like to rotate an icon 360 degrees one way the rotate back the other repeatedly. Going one direction is easy enough what I don't understand is stopping and going the other direction.

```
#loading {
    -webkit-animation: rotation 2s infinite linear;
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotation {
from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(359deg);
}
}

<i id="loading" class="material-icons">autorenew</i>
```

I have tried creating another rotation going the other direction but it doesn't seem to apply.

```
@-webkit-keyframes rotationBackwards {
from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(359deg);
    }
to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
}
}
```

Comment: I guess that is what I'm not understanding is how to apply one then the other and repeat between them.

Comment: @Bhuwan pay attention while editing, you create a non-working snippet .. as the animation will not run with the given CSS, so no need to transform to a snippet because you can create some confusion. The OP shared only the animation code and am sure there is more CSS

Comment: @TemaniAfif In the above code there is css and html both...so I thought it will be good to see css and html separately....and as concern snippet not working, I think it will be good if someone mention to OP that he has to apply `display:inline-block` as well..;)

Comment: @Bhuwan but if you read the question you see `Going one direction is easy enough` which indicates that the OP know how to run the animation and there is no issue width display so for sure there is more CSS and you can see he using material icons and by defaut they are inline-block ... so the OP only share a part of his code

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Transformation doesn't apply on inline elements. You have to make your element a block-level element instead (See [Transformable Elements](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transforms/#transformable-element) on the specifications - If you include the Martial Icons, this will be set by default).

The Animation itself can simply be done with a rotation to 360 degrees for the first half (50%) and a rotation back to 0 degrees for the second half. Mind that the duration of the animation splits into both directions (given your 2s animation, every direction will take 1s).

```css
#loading {
  display: inline-block;
  animation: rotation 2s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes rotation {
  50% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<i id="loading" class="material-icons">autorenew</i>
```

Comment: That will go one direction yes? but how can I apply the other direction and keep repeating back and forth?

Comment: well i guess the issue is not with the display as he seems to be able to run the animation ... so i think better explain the animation

Comment: Yes exactly one direction it works fine. The other not so much.

Comment: Oh that it so obvious now and makes perfect sense. Thanks both of you

Comment: @Ashram and another *small* thing we need to consider is the duration ... using this method means you will have 1s for each direction and initially with your code you are having 2s, so becarefull about this ;)

Comment: it's me again :) since you included the material-icons you no more need to add inline-block as it's already set by default ;)

Comment: Yes you're right, I've already seen that and decided to let it stay part of the answer, as other people might find it useful. I will comment that too, thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Here is another idea by simply using `alternate` value of `animation-direction` and by keeping your initial animation:

```css
#loading {
  animation: rotation 2s infinite linear alternate;
}

@keyframes rotation {
  /*from {
    transform: rotate(0deg); no needed to define this
  }*/
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<i id="loading" class="material-icons">autorenew</i>
```